# Node+NPM on Laradock

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, laradock

I followed everything on the [documentation](http://laradock.io/documentation/#install-node-yarn) on how to enable NPM on the workspace. However, when I run `docker-compose exec workspace bash` then check `node -v` it is missing. The document didn't say too how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Restart docker-compose by using the following commands:

`docker-compose stop`

`docker-compose restart`

Once workspace is up, exec workspace and verify `node -v` again.